# Does Samsung has a feature like second space in Xiaomi?

Tags: samsung, xiaomi, multiple-devices

In Xiaomi we can do second space.

Put certain password we go to first space.

Put another password and we go to second space.

Xiaomi also support dual apps, which is a different feature.

Combined, I think we can have like 4 Whatsapp account per phone.

What about samsung?

Do we have second space in Samsung?

I've heard some devices allow for multiple users sharing a phone.

Say you do regular whatsapp in one device. You do your secret businesses on another user. If someone forces you to open your devices you will just show your first user.

Note: Samsung seems to have ways to allow multiple users on the same phone
https://eu.community.samsung.com/t5/Tablets/Multi-User-switching-accounts-something-you-should-be-aware-of/td-p/1316185

However, there is no way to hide that extra users from say cops.

Android in general can
https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/android-basics-set-up-multiple-user-accounts-same-device-0168597/

However, there is no way to do it like second space.

Comment: http://www.samsungknox.com

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: there are apps for isolating environment and e.g. hiding other apps. Check [Island](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.island).

Unfortunately, lots of Android capabilities are limited by producers - that's the case, too. According to [this link on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/galaxys10/comments/b4fj30/multiple_user_accounts/), people are searching, but with no success. The only devices are tablets, described e.g. [here on Samsung Support page](https://www.samsung.com/uk/support/mobile-devices/how-do-i-create-multiple-user-profiles-for-my-samsung-galaxy-tab-s/) for Galaxy Tab S.

Of course you can enable multi-user functionality by [modifying system files](https://beebom.com/how-enable-multiple-user-accounts-any-android/), but mostly that's not the way a standard user like - warranty issues, triggered Knox, disables access to S Apps... essentially, lots of problems.

So, to sum up - without modifications, **it's impossible on Samsung smartphones to enable multi-user functionality**. Root your phone, and then you'll be able to turn on multi-user, but keep in mind that rooting your device comes with lots of pros **and cons**.